# How can i pass a value from a component to another component in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I have a model called `questions` which has a properties `senderID`, `id`, `expID`, `description`. What i am trying to do is once the user clicks on any of the questions in the list.The `senderID` of the **question which was clicked** gets passed to another component called `AnswerTemplate`. How can i do that

This is the render method

```
` render() {

        const { id: accountID } = this.props.account;
        const question = this.state.questions.filter(({ expID }) => expID === accountID);
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>Answer the questions here!</h1>
            <ul>
              { question.map(({ id, description, senderID }) => (
                <li key={ id }>
                  <a href ={ '/temp' }>{description}</a>
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }`
```

and this is the full code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import AccountActions from '../../../../../Redux/AccountRedux';

class AnswerQuestions extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      questions: []
    };
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.getQuestions();
  }
  getQuestions() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/questions')
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ questions: response.data }, () => {
          console.log(this.state);
        });
      });
  }
  render() {
    const { id: accountID } = this.props.account;
    const question = this.state.questions.filter(({ expID }) => expID === accountID);
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Answer the questions here!</h1>
        <ul>
          { question.map(({ id, description, senderID }) => (
            <li key={ id }>
              <a href ={ '/temp' }>{description}</a>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = store => {
  return {
    account: store.account.data,
    fetching: store.account.fetching
  };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    get: () => dispatch(AccountActions.accountGet())
  };
};
AnswerQuestions.propTypes = {
  get: PropTypes.func,
  fetching: PropTypes.bool,
  account: PropTypes.object,
  question: PropTypes.object
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AnswerQuestions);
```

Comment: What did you try yourself to solve this? Please try to solve your implementational questions yourself before asking for help here over and over. To your question: It heavily depends on the component structure you have above the `AnswerQuestions` component and where you want the answer template to be rendered. Possibly you should dispatch a redux action to put that id into your store and then connect the `AnswerTemplate`to the store to render it. But that is hard to say without knowing the overall structure.

Answer (score 1):

How familiar are you with Redux ?

Since you are using React and Redux, you could call an action **setQuestionID(_id)** for example,

and have a Reducer that stores this ID in the global state.

Then you *connect* your AnswerTemplate.js Component, getting the question id mapped to the props, something like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = store => {
  return {
     question_id: store.question.id,
  };
};
```

Basically you store the question id in the global state.

Would that solve your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to handle your links with router like React Router.

If you are calling the component from inside AnswerQuestions you can do something like:

```
<AnswerTemplate somethingToPass={passThis}/>
```

And inside your AnswerTemplate component you can use `this.props.somethingToPass`.

Hope that helps.

--- edit after comments ---

If you have a parent component for both classes e.g. AnswerParent you need to use AnswerParent's state to handle the data. For example:

```
class AnswerParent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            senderID = '';
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <AnswerQuestions onClick={(senderID) => this.setState(senderID)} />
        <AnswerTemplate senderID={this.state.senderID} />
        )
    }

}
```

And then inside AnswerQuestions

```
<li key={ id }>
     <a onClick={() => this.props.onClick(senderID)} href ={ '/temp' }>{description}</a>
</li>
```

Comment: but i dont want to display `AnswerTemplate` inside `AnswerQuestions`

Comment: It sounds like you may need Redux, unless you manage the values in the state of the parent component of both AnswerTemplate and AnswerQuestions. Do you mind explaining your hierarchy of components?

Comment: I have a folder called `AnswerQuestions` and inside it i have two js files on the same level called `AnswerTemplate.js` and `AnswerQuestions.js`

Comment: Thank you, where are they both being told to render?

Comment: Each is told to render separately in its class. However when i add `<AnswerTemplate somethingToPass={passThis}/>` below `<a href ={ '/temp' }>{description}</a>` they both render together

Comment: Not the render methods inside each component, but the parent component for both classes. I'll update my answer.